# For each segment in a polyline, I need to calculate the sum of an attribute for all objects upstream

Tags: vector, network, rivers

I have a river network in polyline format and I want to accumulate an attribute in the direction of flow. For every single polyline object (stretch of river), I’d like to calculate the sum of an attribute for all objects upstream of it. I’m doing this for the entire river network of England so ideally I’d be able to do this in an efficient manner, preferably where I can make the most of multiple CPU threads. I don’t mind if this is done in R, Python, ArcGIS or QGIS, but I would imagine R/Python would be more efficient.

Comment: If you have ArcMap, RivEX will do this. See help file [here](https://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Accumulateattributeinnetwork.html).

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. 
Either way GBG provided a good starting point to solve this. To do so, I used accumulate attributes in ArcHydro toolbox (http://downloads.esri.com/blogs/hydro/ah2/arc_hydro_tools_2_0_overview.pdf). This hasn't entirely solved my problem as my flow direction doesn't appear to be entirely correct, I'll open a new question for that problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar years ago where I needed to trace upstream of nodes, then sum data contained in polygons that intersected the network.  The tool used was called trace geometric network.  This was coded in ArcGIS 10.5  with Python 2.7.  The ham-fisted code is below for you to sort out for yourself!  I tried to comment the code as much as I remember.

At the time of scripting the actual trace data for each node was not writeable to disk and could only persist in the ArcMap table of contents as layer files.  This meant that the script had to be run in an ArcMap Python window and not an IDE.  The table of contents would get filled with temporary data and crash the machine so I remember having to do some execution and layer removal which slowed things down terribly.  I am unsure how this would playout on a modern 64bit machine or if ESRI sorted out the trace data to disk problem in Pro, nor if this would be possible without dividing your data.

In my case every river intersection was a node in the network.  The tracing happened upstream of every node and the summation data was written to that node.

```py
import sys
import traceback
import numpy
import arcpy

try:
    print "Populate Hydro Edge Flow Lines with Sum Values v2.0..."
    print "Created 9-11-2018 using ArcGIS 10.5, Python 2.7, and NumPy"
    print "Importing modules..."
    

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    print "Getting input data..."

    #inNodes = the trace points to sum from...
    inNodes = r'Z:\GISpublic\GerryG\WaterResources\WRIA1Growth\20181001\flags.shp'
    #Polygon data that intersected the stream data.  These data contained the values that would be summed...
    inSSHIAPsegCat = r'Z:\GISpublic\GerryG\WaterResources\WRIA1Growth\20181001\20181001.gdb\try20181001\drainageswithsummedgrowthdataCleaned'
    #a geometric network built from a hydrologically correct stream layer with proper flow directions and connectivity...
    inGeometricNetwork = r'Z:\GISpublic\GerryG\WaterResources\WRIA1Growth\20181001\20181001.gdb\try20181001\try20181001_Net'

    #These are the attributes that will get created in the pour-points to hold the final upstream summation values...
    nodesFields = ['sum_scen1','sum_scen2','sum_scen3','sum_scen4','sum_scen5a','sum_scen5b','sum_scen6']

    #These are the attributes in the drainages that store the drainage summed total growth estimate.
    #these data and values are the result of a spatial join between the drainages and parcel centroids joined with the
    #projected growth tables.
    watershedsFields = ['Scen1','Scen2','Scen3','Scen4','Scen5a','Scen5b','Scen6']


    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(inNodes)
    for i in nodesFields:    
        if i not in fieldList:
            print"Creating attribute: ", i
            arcpy.AddField_management(inNodes, i, "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")  


    print "Making feature layers..."
    inNodessLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inNodes)
    inSSHIAPsegCatLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inSSHIAPsegCat)

    #now add the the shape attribute to the list...
    nodesFields2 = ["SHAPE@",'sum_scen1','sum_scen2','sum_scen3','sum_scen4','sum_scen5a','sum_scen5b','sum_scen6', 'flagrow']

    print "Working on summations. Please wait, this could take a while...."


    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inNodessLayer, nodesFields2) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print row[8]
            tracelayers = "tracelayers"
            ###   name linesfornetwork needs to be reassigned to your geometric network linework...
            traceselect = tracelayers +"/linesfornetwork"
        
            #For any flag identify all upstream lines...
            arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(inGeometricNetwork, tracelayers, row[0], "FIND_UPSTREAM_ACCUMULATION", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "NO_TRACE_INDETERMINATE_FLOW", "", "", "AS_IS", "", "", "", "AS_IS")
            #Select any drainage polygons that intersect the upstream lines...
        
        
        
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, "CONTAINS", traceselect)
        
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen1', skip_nulls=True)
            sum1 = field['Scen1'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen2', skip_nulls=True)
            sum2 = field['Scen2'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen3', skip_nulls=True)
            sum3 = field['Scen3'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen4', skip_nulls=True)
            sum4 = field['Scen4'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen5a', skip_nulls=True)
            sum5a = field['Scen5a'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen5b', skip_nulls=True)
            sum5b = field['Scen5b'].sum()
        
            field = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray (inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, 'Scen6', skip_nulls=True)
            sum6 = field['Scen6'].sum()
        
       
        
            row[1]= sum1
            row[2]= sum2
            row[3]= sum3
            row[4]= sum4
            row[5]= sum5a
            row[6]= sum5b
            row[7]= sum6
        
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inSSHIAPsegCatLayer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
            print "remove trace now..."
            dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
            for df in dfList:  
                for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):  
                    if lyr.isGroupLayer:  
                        if lyr.name == tracelayers:  
                            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
        
    print "Finished without errors..."        
except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    print msgs
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    print pymsg + "\n"
    print msgs
```